# Как найти индекс элемента у которого id равен переменной

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
var first = getUrlVars()['card'];
var index = $('td').index(first);
```

Comment: цикл foreach возвращает индекс элемента сам элемент и перебираемый массив. Отсюда следует что можно пройтись по массиву и смотреть атрибут id, при совпадении вернуть индекс элемента.

Comment: лучше бы привели входную url, и то, что должно получится на выходе.

Comment: Вместо всей конструкции с `location.href.indexOf`стоило бы использовать `location.search` :)